# Windows Phone 7.5 and 8.0 sistered in the marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, marketplace

I've been wondering about this for awhile. Is it possible to submit 2 versions of the same app (one targeted to 7.8 and one targeted to 8.0) and have them both on the same marketplace submissions so both on both versions of the OS can download, rather than just targeting 7.8 and having 8.0 users use the scaled version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. When submitting an app or a new version of an app on the devcenter, you can upload the XAP targeting WP7 and the XAP targeting WP8. The user will automatically download the appropriate one.

Comment: If you need more details, read this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdatingMyWindowsPhoneAppToWindowsPhone8.aspx

Comment: Oh, it's really that simple? haha. Thanks, and merry Christmas :).